# Using a string in AppResources

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using `LocalizedResources` to get localization for my WP 8.1 app. But if I used a code like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string xyz = string.Empty;
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("znam", out xyz);
    tekstZnamenitosti.Text = AppResources.tekstTrsat;
}
```

then I would have to have many if statements to check for each `znamenitost`. Is there a way to use

```
tekstZnamenitosti.Text = AppResources.xyz;
```

where xyz is a string that I made before and in it is the value passed from a page which I navigated from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the `AppResources` value using **ResourceManager**:

```
tekstZnamenitosti.Text = AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString("xyz");
```

Comment: You are welcome.If it's helpful for you, please mark it as the Answer. So more people can get it. Thx!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me :) I tried but it said to wait for 8 minutes and I just forgot!

Answer (score 2):

Just to extend [Chris Shao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24258163/2681948)(+1) a little - maybe somebody find it usefull:

Create special class for your *Resources*:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
  public class AppRes
  {
    private static ResourceLoader load = new ResourceLoader();
    private static string GetProperty([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) { return propertyName; }

    public static string PropertyName { get { return load.GetString(GetProperty()); } }
  }
}
```

In App.xaml add *Key* to resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:AppRes x:Key="Localized"/>
    // ... rest of the code.
```

Now you can easily use your *Resources* from code:

```
string fromResources = AppRes.PropertyName;
```

and in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyName, Source={StaticResource Localized}}" ...
```

One thing you have to do is once you add your *Resource* to *Resources.resw*, you have to add another line:

```
public static string NewPropertyName { get { return load.GetString(GetProperty()); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can have the string value in the `App.xaml.cs` such as

```
 public static string xyz;
```

Then you can save the value you wanted to the variable you created in the App.xaml.cs.

```
tekstZnamenitosti.Text = App.xyx;
```

You could use this variable anywhere in the app.