# Using multiple string resources from .resw file into ContentDialog

Tags: xaml, dialog, winrt-xaml, uwp

I would like to set the PrimaryButtonText, SecondaryButtonText and Title attributes of a ContentDialog with strings from my .resw file. Unfortunately Ι can do this only for one attribute using x:Uid, since setting x:Uid two times inside ContentDialog can not be accepted. I even tried to do something like that:

```
<ContentDialog>
<ContentDialog.PrimaryButtonText x:Uid="DialogConfirm" />
    <ContentDialog.SecondaryButtonText x:Uid="DialogCancel" />
</ContentDialog>
```

But I got an exception

> XBF generation error code 0x09c8

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set *x:Uid* only for *ContentDialog* then in resources file set apropriate properties ([take a look at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx)):

```xml
<ContentDialog x:Uid="myDialog">
    <!--your dialog-->
</ContentDialog>
```

In *Resources.resw* set:

```
myDialog.PrimaryButtonText ->  text for primary button
myDialog.SecondaryButtonText ->  text for secondary button
```

As for [more guidelines and help, see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965328.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I don't like, is that for every custom  ContentDialog I create, I need to add 3 string resources more because of the Title which is different for each one.

Comment: @Stam You may take a look at [alternative implementation of localized resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24258472/2681948) - in some cases I use it.