# Localisation in WIndows Phone 8.1

Tags: localization, windows-phone-8.1

Hi i am working on Windows phone,

Step :1  I am trying to learn localisation. I added 2 resource files.(AppResources.resx and AppResourcesfr-FR.resx)

Step 2: I created a class LocalizedStrings. It has a property of type AppResources

```
private static App1.AppResources localizedResource = new pp1.AppResources();

public App1.AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return localizedResource; } }
```

Step 3 :In the App.Xaml i added a ApplicationResource

```
<local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="using:App1" x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
```

Step 4 :In my Login.Xaml I just added Like this

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbTitlePanel" Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.AppTitle, Source=LocalizedStrings}"/>
```

My resource file :
[image]

Data is not binding. I did not get understand what the isuue is?

Comment: Are you creating Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app or Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT (Universal app)?

Comment: am creating windoes phone 8.1 winrt

Comment: I've implemented it [like in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24258472/2681948).

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the WinRT app, there is a different approach for creating localized applications. [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/862152/Localization-in-Windows-Universal-Apps) is good article about it. 
In short, you have to use `x:Uid` in you controls (instead of names) and add resources with properties, eg. `tbTitlePanel.Text`.
Above article will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the link. But i tried this. It was working for me. but want to know what mistake i made in this