# Localize UWP Appllication

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm porting application from Windows Phone 8.1 to UWP and I have problem with getting strings from resources. In WP 8.1 I could get string by writing:

```
Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.lDownloadStatus , Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

Is there any similar solution in UWP or I have to set x:UID, and then in resource file set for example: "Button.Content | SampleContent" ?

Comment: You can either use `x:Uid` or create something similar to *LocalizedStrings* by using *ResourceLoader* - [small example in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24258472/2681948).

Answer (score 2):

You should create folder "Strings" in you project, for French language create inside it another folder with country LCID name (fr-fr for France). And create there resource.resw file.

If you want to use value in TextBlock.Text, name your field in .resw file as "Hello.Text" and give it a value "Bonjour".

Go to your TextBlock and set x:Uid="Hello".

Change yor language with ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "fr-fr".

Comment: can you not create folder just as fr? instead fr-fr? for example if i create de-De, it is only for Germany, Should I create another folder for au-De for austia german?

Comment: @batmaci you can create only fr. It will cover all countries with the French language.

Comment: `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "fr-fr"` Where to add this line? As far as I know we just need to change `Default language` attribute in Package.appxmanifest file which is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use x:uid to load your resource strings or you can get resource strings from back end by using ResourceManager.
Here is a sample from MSDN: [How to create a localization UWP App](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/how-to-create-a-localizatio-c61f4b37).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have made very good experiences with the CustomResources.

Just create a new class anywhere in your UI project which inherits from CustomXamlResourceLoader and implement the method below:

```
protected override object GetResource(string resourceId, string objectType, string propertyName, string propertyType)
    {
        var parts = resourceId.Split('|');

        if (parts.Length != 2)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        return ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse(parts[0]).GetString(split[1]);
    }
```

Then you create Resource-Files, I used to name them like the page I am on, i.e. "MainPage.resw".

That's it, now you can start use your resources from XAML:

```
Text="{CustomResource MainPage|MyResourceKey}"
```

Of course, the seperator can be anything you want to, it is not limited to a Pipe. Just make sure you use the same seperator in your ResourceLoader and your XAMLs.

You won't get a preview in the Designer, but the big advantage is that you can split your resource files and don't have to put everything into one.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/customresource-markup-extension for more information.